Mapperly: how to do mapping multiple sources to a single type with `required ... { get; init; }` properties?
Is there any way with Mapperly to return a new object from multiple sources? something like this:
[Mapper]
public partial class Mapper {
    public partial VehicleRecord From(VehicleContract Vehicle, string userId);
}

The reason is that I need to create a VehicleRecord to be stored in the database:
public class VehicleRecord {
    [DynamoDBHashKey]  public required string UserId { get; init; }
    [DynamoDBProperty] public required string ModelName { get; init; }  
    /*
    ... more properties ...
    */
}

From two sources:

The authenticated string userId = GetAuthenticatedUserId()
The VehicleContract that is passed in the request body:

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostVehicle([FromBody] VehicleContract vehicle) {
    string userId = GetAuthenticatedUserId();
    VehicleRecord dbRecord = mapper.From(vehicle);
    // ... store in DB ...
}


[DataContract]
public class VehicleContract {
    [DataMember] public required string ModelName { get; init; }
    /*
    ... more properties ...
    */
}

I tried MapProperty in any way I could think of, but couldn't get it to work with two sources. I also pored over the documentation to find a way to do this, but couldn't find anything. Is there a way to do this with Mapperly?

Have you tried the latest 4.0.0-next.* release? It introduces additional mapping parameters, which should exactly be what you are looking for.

@latonz yay it's working!!  thanks!
